# How to check if application is running as scheduled task without user login?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have an application that is run both manually and as a scheduled task (without user login). Now when closing the application (main form's `OnCloseQuery` event), I want to display a confirmation dialog if running with user login.

How can I check if my application is running as a scheduled task without user login (trigger "On computer start")?

Comment: Why not just pass some parameter (sort of `/noconfirmonexit`) when running as a scheduled task ? Then you could simply check if that parameter was passed and according to that show the confirmation dialog. It would also bring to the *experienced* users higher level of UX when they configure their shortcut to use that parameter (I hate these annoying dialogs personally :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Far and away the simplest way to achieve your goal is to configure the scheduled task to pass an argument to the process. The process can use the presence, or otherwise, of this argument to make its decision.